# CROSSTAB and DATEPART in postgres? Does it work?

Tags: postgresql, date, group-by, pivot, crosstab

I have a column with dates formatted like 2015-02-19 and I'm trying to pull the year out and have the year as separate columns to show the total sales for the year.  My source query works fine but when trying to run the full query, I get a syntax error for yearly_sales

```
SELECT *
FROM CROSSTAB(
    'SELECT sales_agent, date_part('year', sales_date) AS yearly_sales, SUM(daily_sales)
     FROM agent_sales_table
     GROUP BY sales_agent, yearly_sales
     ORDER BY sales_agent, yearly_sales') AS source (sales_agent text, 2015 numeric, 2016 numeric);
```

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "year"
LINE 3:  'SELECT sales_agent, date_part('year', sales_date) AS yearly_sales, SUM(daily_s...
                                         ^
```

So, does datepart work with crosstab?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would simply use conditional aggregation here. I find that the syntax is easier to understand; also, this would possibly be a more efficient solution, especially if you use the right syntax to filter the dates, that is:

```
select
    sales_agent,
    sum(daily_sales) filter(where sales_date >= date '2015-01-01' and sales_date < date '2016-01-01') sales_2015
    sum(daily_sales) filter(where sales_date >= date '2016-01-01' and sales_date < date '2017-01-01') sales_2016
from mytable
group by sales_agent
```

This query might take advantage of an index on `sales_agent, sales_date)`.

You can easily extend the `select` clause to handle more years. It might also be a good idea to add a `where` clause to restrict the rows to aggregate earlier. Matter of fact, if you just want 2015 and 2016, the query can be written as:

```
select
    sales_agent,
    sum(daily_sales) filter(where sales_date <  date '2016-01-01') sales_2015
    sum(daily_sales) filter(where sales_date >= date '2016-01-01') sales_2016
from mytable
where sales_date >= date '2015-01-01' and sales_date < date '2017-01-01'
group by sales_agent
```

Answer (score 0):

SELECT *
FROM CROSSTAB(
'SELECT sales_agent, date_part(' 'year' ', sales_date) AS yearly_sales, SUM(daily_sales)
FROM agent_sales_table
GROUP BY sales_agent, yearly_sales
ORDER BY sales_agent, yearly_sales') AS source (sales_agent text, 2015 numeric, 2016 numeric);

Comment: Use just two singe quotes not use double quotes